# How to configure gnome-shell extensions installed from the official website?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, extension, dconf

I always configure installed gnome-shell extensions from dconf-editor, but after installing extensions from the [official site](https://extensions.gnome.org/) i couldn't configure the installed extensions from the official site (i didn't found the them in dconf-editor under org >> gnome >> shell >> extensions).
so how to configure installed extensions from the official site ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for now you can not do that.

the extensions from the official site which still in alpha, cannot be modified using dconf. (at least some of them).

but you can still modify them, by going to the `extension.js` and `.css` files in `/home/username/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions.`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me. I edited the css file of an extension I installed but saw no changes.

Answer (score 2):

In Gnome 3 you can configure extension using this link:
https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

You can turn them on and off and also do some advanced config on some extensions.

Best,
Juergen

Answer (score 0):

I use gnome-tweak-tool for this.

You can get it here:
[image: Install via the software center]